# My dog is protective in the neighborhood

Tags: dogs

### Background

My wife and I got our female St. Bernard (Ellie) about a year and a half ago from a family, but don't know much about her past before they got her (only had her a few months).  We think she's about 3 years old now and weighs about 115 pounds.  She is extremely mild mannered and laid back with people and kids, but when my wife and I walk Ellie around the neighborhood she gets extremely excited and fairly aggressive towards other dogs (some days she's much worse than others, and some days she has very little reaction).  I've tried using treats to reward, but it seemed like she got more excited knowing she would get a treat when she saw the other dog.  We've taken her to pets stores and the dog park, where she's a little anxious, but otherwise just fine around the other dogs.  She's also great at the vet's when she's out with the other dogs.

### Question

Why does Ellie act this way only around our apartment/neighborhood and what are some solutions to help reduce the protective/territorial instincts?

Comment: Sounds to me like she's just a bit territorial.

Comment: Are the dogs she sees around the neighbourhood the same dogs that she sees in pet stores and the dog park?  Is she off the lead in both situations, or is this something she she shows on the lead only?

Comment: No, they are different dogs.  She will come up to meet the dogs in the pet stores and is just a little shy/anxious, but does well.  Around the neighborhood just the sight of a dog gets her worked up and it's hard to let her get close to even meet the dog.  She's on the lead when we're outside (if she gets on a scent she won't listen to come back all the time).

Comment: Your neighborhood is her home.  She is just being protective of her home. I think you are on the right track rewarding her.  Try only rewarding her with a treat when she sits and stops barking or pulling you towards another dog when walking around the neighborhood.  Also, more frequent walks around the neighborhood could be what she needs to feel more comfortable around those dogs.